# How can I use vue variable inside laravel blade's image src?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am trying to use a vue variable inside blade and image src attribute but vue gives template compiling errors.

Where is what I am trying to do

```
<img src="uploads/@{{authUser.profilePic}}"/>
```

I could separate this as a pure template but vue template loads little bit slower than a blade file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:`

Comment: It gives ` Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead` but if I add :src it gives different error complain about {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpolation inside attributes is not available on Vue 2.  Instead you use `v-bind:src` or the shortcut `:src` to bind a Javascript expression to `src`.

```
<img :src="'uploads/' + authUser.profilePic"/>
```

The javascript expression being string concatenation:

```
'uploads/' + authUser.profilePic
```

Comment: Thanks. Got confused with laravel's {{}} and @ but thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Yeah, you'd use `@{{ var }}` anywhere outside of attributes.